# ASP.NET MVC Appends ' ?RouteValueDictionary ' to my routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm doing some changes on my routes, and suddenly the following is appearing in my url's as a querystring:

```
?RouteValueDictionary=System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary
```

So, my url's now look like

```
http://localhost:20367/Search/AdvancedSearchResults?RouteValueDictionary=System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary
```

How do I make it disappear?

I know the routing puts it in there, because it cannot find route values for the viewmodel that's passed along, but I can't seem to fix it...

Comment: Can you post your `RegisterRoutes` method?  There's not really enough information to go on here.

Comment: What do your routes look like?  What did they look like?

Comment: Well, I'm adding to existing routes. This part is configured to handle paging as well. I'll update my question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect your call to Html.ActionLink is picking the wrong overload. You might need to add an extra parameter at the end to force .NET to pick the right overload:

`Html.ActionLink("click here, "SomeAction", "SomeController", routeValues, null)`